# Не устанавливаются глобальные ограничения параметров в Route

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('user/{id}/{name}/{age?}', function ($id, $name, $age = 'noage') {
    return 'User '.$id.' '.$name.' '.$age;
});
```

Пытаюсь установить глобальное ограничение для id в `RouteServiceProvider.php`
Сейчас он имеет такое содержание:

```
public function boot() {
  $this->setRootControllerNamespace();

  if ($this->app->routesAreCached()) {
      $this->loadCachedRoutes();
  } else {
      $this->loadRoutes();

  $this->app->booted(function () {
    $this->app['router']->getRoutes()->refreshNameLookups();
    $this->app['router']->getRoutes()->refreshActionLookups();
    });
  }
}
```

Добавить `Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+')` (как в документации) туда не могу, выдает ошибку 
`Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\Route' not found`

Что я делаю не так? Версия 5.5.58

Comment: Route::get('user/{id}/{name}/{age?}', function ($id, $name, $age = 'noage') {
    return 'User '.$id.' '.$name.' '.$age;
})->where('id',[0-9]+);

Comment: а если так: `\Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+')`

Comment: @P.Fateev, спасибо